# Extra Object is formed while making Game in Opengl during each move

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

Extra Object(Block,not OOP) is formed while playing Game in Opengl during each move.
I tried to made a Bloxerz game ,in which block is moved with keys on a board , The problem is every time, as i move the  block, a new Image of block is formed under the board. 
I can't find trace of this thing
I think ,there is  nothing wrong with the code and logic except it is written nonprofessional like OpenGl programmers write. 
There must be some thing missing,some method to stop this.
In order to make every thing visible,i have shared all my code.
Following is my code:

```
int s=-1;
int stage=0;
int arr[]={5,5,5,4,4,4,4,5,9,9,10,9,10,8,9,8,10,7,11,7,11,6,10,6};

int fallcount=0;
int fallset=0;
int rot[]={0,0,0};
int axis=0;
int a=0;

double x=0.8,y=1.3,z=1;
double move1=0;
int moved=0;
int pos=1;
int position;

void Init()
{
         x=0.8;
         y=1.3;
         z=1;
         move1=0;
         moved=0;
         pos=1;
         position=1;
         fallcount=0;

   }
  void wait ( int seconds )
  {
clock_t endwait;
endwait = clock () + seconds * CLOCKS_PER_SEC ;
while (clock() < endwait) {}
  }

   void FallOn()
   {
     if(position==1||position==3)
    {
   if(x<=-0.7||y<=-0.7||x>=11.3||y>=11.3)
{
  Init();
}
   }
     if(stage==1)
    {
      if(x>=2.8&&y<=5.3&&y>=3.8)
      {
Init();
   }
if((x>=1.8)&&(x<=5.8)&&(y>=8.8))
{
Init();
}

 }
     }
    void checkpos(int arg)
   {
if((position==1)&&(arg==1))
{
position=1;
x=x+1;              
return;
}
else if((position==1)&&(arg==2))
{
position=2;
rot[1]=-1;
rot[2]=0;
rot[3]=0;
y=y+2;
x=x+0.5;                
return;
}
else if((position==1)&&(arg==3))
{
position=1;
rot[1]=0;
rot[2]=-1;
rot[3]=0;
x=x-1;
return;
     }
   else if((position==1)&&(arg==4))
    {

position=2;
rot[1]=0;
rot[2]=0;
rot[3]=1;
y=y-1;
x=x+0.5;        
   return;
}
      if((position==2)&&(arg==1))
      {

   position=3;
rot[1]=0;
rot[2]=1;
rot[3]=0;
x=x+1;
y=y-0.5;
   return;
   }
    else if((position==2)&&(arg==2))
    {

position=1;
rot[1]=0;
rot[2]=-1;
rot[3]=0;
y=y+1;
x=x-0.5;


   return;
     }
    else if((position==2)&&(arg==3))
    {

position=3;
rot[1]=0;
rot[2]=-1;
rot[3]=0;
x=x-2;  
y=y-0.5;
    return;
    }

    else if((position==2)&&(arg==4))
    {

position=1;
rot[1]=0;
rot[2]=0;
rot[3]=1;
y=y-2;
x=x-0.5;

  return;
   }
 if((position==3)&&(arg==1))
 { 

position=2;
rot[1]=0;
rot[2]=1;
rot[3]=0;
x=x+2;
y=y+0.5;

  return;
   }
   else if((position==3)&&(arg==2))
   { 

position=3;
rot[1]=0;
rot[2]=0;
rot[3]=-1;
y=y+1;


    return;
     }
    else if((position==3)&&(arg==3))
    {

position=2;
rot[1]=0;
rot[2]=-1;
rot[3]=0;
x=x-1;
y=y+0.5;

     return;
     } 

   else if((position==3)&&(arg==4))
   {
position=3;
rot[1]=1;
rot[2]=0;
rot[3]=0;
y=y-1;
    return;
   }
  }
   void draw_string( int x, int y,int z ,const char * buffer ) {
// function to draw a string in glut

glRasterPos3i( x, y,z );

// i think its safe to assume a null terminator appears somewhere
while( *buffer )
    glutBitmapCharacter( (void *)GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24, *(buffer++) );

   }

   void Display()
   {
FallOn();
glLoadIdentity();
//glu look at
gluLookAt(-30,-30,30,2.5,4,0,0,0,1);
//***********************************************Board************************************************************************
     if(stage==0)
     {
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    for(int i=0;i<=12;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<=12;j++)
{
        glColor3d(1,0,1);
        glVertex3d(i,i,0);
        glVertex3d(j,i,0);  
        glVertex3d(j,j,0);
        glVertex3d(i,j,0);
}
}
        glEnd();
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glColor3d(0,0,0);
        glVertex3d(arr[s+1],arr[s+2],0);
        glVertex3d(arr[s+3],arr[s+4],0);    
        glVertex3d(arr[s+5],arr[s+6],0);
        glVertex3d(arr[s+7],arr[s+8],0);
glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINES);
glColor3d(0,0,0);
    for(int i=0;i<=12;i++)
{   
    glVertex3d(0,i,0);
    glVertex3d(12,i,0);
    glVertex3d(i,0,0);
    glVertex3d(i,12,0);
}
    glEnd();
 }
   else if(stage==1)
   {
glFlush();
    glClear(GL_CLIP_PLANE0);
    glClear(GL_ACCUM_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    for(int i=0;i<=12;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<=12;j++)
{
        glColor3d(1,0,1);
        glVertex3d(i,i,0);
        glVertex3d(j,i,0);  
        glVertex3d(j,j,0);
        glVertex3d(i,j,0);
}
}
glEnd();

glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glColor3d(0,0,0);
        glVertex3d(3,4,0);
        glVertex3d(3,6,0);  
        glVertex3d(12,6,0);
        glVertex3d(12,4,0);
        glEnd();
        glFlush();

        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glColor3d(0,0,0);
        glVertex3d(2,12,0);
        glVertex3d(7,12,0); 
        glVertex3d(7,9,0);
        glVertex3d(2,9,0);
        glEnd();
        glFlush();


            s=7;
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glColor3d(0,0,0);
        glVertex3d(arr[s+1],arr[s+2],0);
        glVertex3d(arr[s+3],arr[s+4],0);    
        glVertex3d(arr[s+5],arr[s+6],0);
        glVertex3d(arr[s+7],arr[s+8],0);
        glEnd();    

glBegin(GL_LINES);
glColor3d(0,0,0);
    for(int i=0;i<=12;i++)
    {   
    glVertex3d(0,i,0);
    glVertex3d(12,i,0);
    glVertex3d(i,0,0);
    glVertex3d(i,12,0);
    }
    glEnd();
   }
   else if(stage==2)
   {
glFlush();
glClear(GL_CLIP_PLANE0);
    glClear(GL_ACCUM_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    for(int i=0;i<=12;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<=12;j++)
{
        glColor3d(1,0,1);
        glVertex3d(i,i,0);
        glVertex3d(j,i,0);  
        glVertex3d(j,j,0);
        glVertex3d(i,j,0);
}
}
glEnd();

glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glColor3d(0,0,0);
        glVertex3d(3,11,0);
        glVertex3d(9,11,0); 
        glVertex3d(9,0,0);
        glVertex3d(3,0,0);
        glEnd();
        glFlush();


            s=15;
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glColor3d(0,0,0);
        glVertex3d(arr[s+1],arr[s+2],0);
        glVertex3d(arr[s+3],arr[s+4],0);    
        glVertex3d(arr[s+5],arr[s+6],0);
        glVertex3d(arr[s+7],arr[s+8],0);
        glEnd();    

glBegin(GL_LINES);
glColor3d(0,0,0);
    for(int i=0;i<=12;i++)
    {   
    glVertex3d(0,i,0);
    glVertex3d(12,i,0);
    glVertex3d(i,0,0);
    glVertex3d(i,12,0);
    }
    glEnd();
      }


            if(moved==0)
    {
                    glPushMatrix();
                    glColor3d(1,0,0);
                    glTranslated(x,y,z);
                    glScalef(1,2.1,1);
                    glutSolidCube(.9);
                    glPopMatrix();
    }   
    if(moved==1)
    {
        if(position==1)
        {           
                    glPushMatrix();
                    glColor3d(1,0,0);
                    glTranslated(x,y,z);
                    glScalef(1,2.1,1);
                    glutSolidCube(.9);
                    glPopMatrix();
                    moved=0;

        }
        else if(position==2)
        {   
                    cout<<"2:-  "<<"x="<<x<<"y="<<y<<"z="<<z<<"position="<<position<<endl;
                    if(((x==4.3&&y==4.3)&&stage==0)||((x==9.3&&y==8.3)&&stage==1))
                    {       
                    cout<<"Event Happened"<<endl;
                    z=z-1;
                    cout<<"Stage Cleared"<<endl;
                    glPushMatrix();
                    glColor3d(1,0,0);
                    glTranslated(x,y,z);
                    glScalef(1,1,2.1);
                    glutSolidCube(.9);
                    glPopMatrix();
                    moved=0;
                    wait(1);
                    Init();
                    stage+=1;
                    glutPostRedisplay();
                    glFlush();
                    }
                    else if((x==10.3&&y==6.3)&&(stage==2))
                    {
                    cout<<"Event Happened"<<endl;
                    z=z-1;
                    cout<<"Stage Cleared"<<endl;
                    glPushMatrix();
                    glColor3d(1,0,0);
                    glTranslated(x,y,z);
                    glScalef(1,1,2.1);
                    glutSolidCube(.9);
                    glPopMatrix();
                    moved=0;
                    wait(1);
                    Init();
                    cout<<"Congratulations!!!!! You Won"<<endl;
                    stage=0;
                    glFlush();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    glPushMatrix();
                    glColor3d(1,0,0);
                    glTranslated(x,y,z);
                    glScalef(1,1,2.1);
                    glutSolidCube(.9);
                    glPopMatrix();
                    moved=0;                        
                    }

        }

        else if(position==3)
        {
                    glPushMatrix();
                    glColor3d(1,0,0);
                    glTranslated(x,y,z);
                    glScalef(2.1,1,1);
                    glutSolidCube(.9);
                    glPopMatrix();
                    moved=0;
        }
        moved=3;
  }
glFlush();
glutSwapBuffers();

  }
  void Resize(int h,int w)
 {
if(h==0)
{
h=1;
}
float ratio=w*1/h;
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glViewport(0,0,w,h);
gluPerspective(14.0f ,ratio,0.1f,100.f);
 glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
void Board(unsigned char key,int x,int y)
{
switch (key)
{
 case 'w':
 case 'W':
move1=1;
moved=1;
axis=1;
checkpos(1);
    glFlush();
glutSwapBuffers();
glutPostRedisplay();
break;
  case 'a':                     
  case 'A':
move1=2;
moved=1;
axis=2;
checkpos(2);    
    glFlush();
glutSwapBuffers();
glutPostRedisplay();
break;
case 'S':
case 's':
move1=3;
moved=1;
axis=1;
checkpos(3);
glFlush();
glutSwapBuffers();
glutPostRedisplay();
break;
    case 'd':
    case 'D':
move1=4;
moved=1;
axis=2;
checkpos(4);
glFlush();
glutSwapBuffers();
glutPostRedisplay();
break;
default:
    break;
 }
    }
     int main(int argc, char **argv)
      {
       glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB|GLUT_DEPTH);
      glutInitWindowSize(400, 400);
      glutInitWindowPosition(200, 200);
      glutCreateWindow("3D Object in OpenGL");
      Init();
      glutDisplayFunc(Display);
      glutReshapeFunc(Resize);
  glutKeyboardFunc(Board);
   glutMainLoop();
return 0;
}
```

Do openGl show anomalies?

Comment: You should consider formatting your code properly if you want people to read it.

Comment: The person who will know the solution of my problem will not bother to go deeply in my code

Comment: @RetiredNinja You can tell me , "Do openGl show such anomalies?"

Comment: Okay, I just sent your code through a pretty formatter to make it readable, and it's quite full of WTFs. What do you think `glClear(GL_CLIP_PLANE0)` does? (hint: It's raises an invalid value error). Why are you calling SwapBuffers followed by a glutPostRedisplay in a input event handlers. You never put graphics code into a event handler. Never! Why do you have several glutPostRedisplay calls in the drawing code, with the occasional SwapBuffers mixed in? /// Clearly you have absolutely no understanding whatsoever what those functions do and how they interact. That's pure Cargo Cult Programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` to the top of your display function.

Comment: Game is not smooth, as stages goes on, Frame blinks and show all content for 2,3 mili seconds as i move the block and then every thing is fine until next move.

Comment: Well, to be honest with you, the code doesn't look all that great, I just noticed you weren't ever clearing the buffer so you had artifacts from previous frames when you didn't draw over them.

Comment: Will you please share some link with me ,how could i make it better

Answer (score 3):

> Extra Object (Block,not OOP) is formed while playing Game in Opengl during each move.

What are those "objects" you're talking about? There are no objects in OpenGL. There are only points, lines an triangles, drawn to a pixel based framebuffer.

In OpenGL there is no scene, there are no models, there are no objects. Any notion of a scene or objects are your burden to implement. On the OpenGL side, whenever something changes the only correct way to go about this is to perform a full redraw: Clear the whole buffer and draw the scene from scratch.

> I think ,there is nothing wrong with the code and logic except it is written nonprofessional like OpenGl programmers write.

I'm sorry to break it to you, but your code is full of misconceptions and logic errors.

> There must be some thing missing, some method to stop this.

It's rather simple: Don't treat OpenGL like something it is not. OpenGL is not a scene graph. Treat it like a pencil you use to draw onto a piece of paper provided to you by the operating system. If you want to draw some flip page book animation you draw each frame from scratch, and that's how you do it in OpenGL as well.

---

BTW, there are tools like Uncrustify that make your code readble. The mess you posted is unberable.

#### Update

Okay, I just sent your code through a pretty formatter to make it readable, and it's quite full of WTFs.

What do you think glClear(GL_CLIP_PLANE0) does? (hint: It's raises an invalid value error)

Why are you calling SwapBuffers followed by a glutPostRedisplay in a input event handlers. You never put graphics code into a event handler. Never!

Why do you have several glutPostRedisplay calls in the drawing code, with the occasional SwapBuffers mixed in?

Clearly you have absolutely no understanding whatsoever what those functions do and how they interact. That's pure Cargo Cult Programming.

Please, please, please go back to an introductionionary tutorial on OpenGL and work through it step for step. Don't skip things, because you clearly demonstrated you lack even the most basic understanding of how things like a double buffer works (what does swapping mean), how calling `glFinish` is completely uncalled for because the buffer swap implies it.

I recommend you this one: http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut